# CakePHP multirule validation

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to get multiple rules to run during an upload validation.  One validation is built in and one is custom.  The custom one works fine however the built in one is not working.  The custom one `extension` was working on another field earlier just fine.  Do I have this setup correct?

```
var $validate = array(
        'description' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'This field cannot be left blank.',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'Filedata' => array(
            'rule' => array('FileExtCheck'),
            'message' => 'Please supply a valid type.',
            'required' => true
        ),
        'Thumbdata' => array(
            'dimensions'=>array(
                'rule' => array('dimensions','120','142'),
                'message' => 'Your image dimensions are incorrect: 120x142'
            ),
            'extension' => array(
                'rule' => array('extension'=>array('jpg','jpeg','png')),
                'message' => 'Please supply a valid type.',
                'required'=>true
            )
        )
    );
```

The one I am having issue with is `Thumbdata`.  I want the Thumbdata field to be required and make sure it has correct dimensions and is an image of jpg, jpeg or png.  I don't want animated gif's.

Comment: Well, let's hope that you create custom validation rule dimensions, because it's not in CakePHP's core validations list. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you have a syntax error - unnecessary `=>`. Should be:

`'rule' => array('extension', array('jpg','jpeg','png')),`